# Including .jar file into cordova plugin

Tags: java, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I need to include 3rd party plugin `.jar` to my custom cordova plugin.
I can't find any way to do this.

f.e. some of my actual code looks like this (in `plugin.xml`):

```
<platform name="android">
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="AztecReader">
                <param name="android-package" value="com.example.aztecreadermobilas.AztecReaderPlugin"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>

        <source-file src="src/android/AztecReaderPlugin.java" target-dir="src/com/example/aztecreadermobilas" />      
</platform>
```

Libraries I need to include:

```
/libs
    /armeabi
        /libAztecLibrary.so
    /armeabi_v2
        /libAzteclibraryv2.so
    /AztecReader.jar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an example potentially covering your use case:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas/blob/master/plugin.xml

Have a look at line 31. It seems that precompiled libraries (in this case Android/libs/armeabi/libFastCanvasJNI.so) may be included via source-file directive.

I don't know if this will work for java class files as well. You may accomplish this by extracting the jar and adding each contained class file as source-file. Just have a try.

AztecReader seems to be available as source code, so you could at the sources (java files) directly to your plugin. They will be compiled during app build. This seems to be the obviously easiest way to integrate the reader in your plugin.

Comment: It does. Example:
    <source-file src="src/android/libs/lcrypto-jdk15.jar" target-dir="libs" />

Answer (score 0):

.so .jar file, the same as .java file, just use:

`<source-file src="path/to/foo.so" target-dir="libs/" />`

tips: yourApp/platform/android/ is an android project dir, after *cordova build android*, you can debug it in Android Studio as normal. What boring is, every time you modify the plugin code, you have to remove and re-add it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `lib-file` element to your plugin.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
  <lib-file src="AztecReader.jar" />
</platform>
```

See [Plugin.xml reference documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#lib-file):

> For Android, the `<lib-file>` element is used for installing .jar files in the project's libs directory. It supports only the src attribute which contains the relative path to the .jar file.